# Yaoi manga about a guy that transmigrated into a novel and his brother can read minds

Tags: story-identification, manga

I’m trying to find the name of this manhwa; it’s about a guy that transmigrated (guyA) and he has a brother/step-brother (GuyB) That can read minds (GuyB is the Male Lead). Since GuyB can read guyA’s mind he knows what he is really thinking so he ends up falling for him but guyA is just trying to get GuyB and Female Lead together.

There is also a talking black cat? That is telling guyA the mission?

In one of the chapters GuyB ends up meeting the FL but doesn’t really care much for her so guyA ends up dressing up as her or something like that and goes to meet GuyB but of course GuyB knows who he is since the powers made him aware.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  And am I understanding this correctly, that the second guy ends up falling for his _brother_?

Comment: It was a few months ago but to my understanding it’s more like he is adopted or something like that but guyA his soul is trapped in the novel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got you. The title is ***[I Have to Be a Great Villain](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/w627zkf/i-want-to-be-a-big-baddie)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> A true villain needs to be ruthless, evil, and self-destructive! After torturing the protagonist to hell and back, they will exit the scene fabulously with a bang as their work is done. Wang Yi was determined to act that kind of villain. Unfortunately… His male lead could read minds. (:з)∠*) "You mongrel!" Mr. Yi chuckled as he looked down on the novel's male lead. Suddenly, a thought bubble filled with cute emojis (⁄ ⁄ ⁄ω⁄ ⁄ ⁄) with the words "You're so cute…" appeared in front of Qin. Qin: ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct manga, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.